# Build paths of edge keys in nested hashes in ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.6

I have a nested hash with multiple levels and I want to get all the possible paths of each edge key from the root as dot notation string. For example

`{a: {m: {b: 2}, c: {d: {e: nil}}}}`

I would like to produce an array of elements like the one below

`['a.m.b', 'a.c.d.e']`

Comment: What is the desired return value if the hash is `{a: {m: {b: 2, c: 1}}}`?

Comment: ```['a.m.b', 'a.m.c']```

Comment: See "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)". We want to know what you tried. Currently it looks like you didn't try and want us to write code for you. "[Writing The Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)"
is also useful.

Comment: I posted a problem I wanted to solve. This is only a piece of the bigger function. I am not going to post the whole function here.

Comment: I find the title of the question very good. That's what the upvote is for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def recurse(h)
  h.flat_map do |k,v|
    if v.is_a?(Hash)      
      recurse(v).map { |str| "%s.%s" % [k.to_s, str] }
    else
      k.to_s
    end
  end
end
```

```
h = {a: {m: {b: 2, c:1}, d: {e: {f: nil}, g: 3}}}
recurse(h)
  #=> ["a.m.b", "a.m.c", "a.d.e.f", "a.d.g"]
```

```
h = {a: {m: {b: 2, c:1}, d: 5 }, e: {f: {g: nil}, h: 3}}
recurse(h)
  #=> ["a.m.b", "a.m.c", "a.d", "e.f.g", "e.h"]
```

Comment: Cary this works for hashes. I am trying to see how can I adapt it now to loop also keys that have arrays of hashes. For example ```{a: [{b: 1, c:3}]}```

Comment: Best to post a separate question.